# Is there a way to liquefy a super absorbent polymer without using salt?

Tags: water, polymers, absorption

I understand that once a SAP absorbs a liquid it becomes a type of gel and that this gel can be liquefied by applying salt, are there other methods to liquefy this gel without using salt?

Answer (score 1):

change the pH to less than 3.   absorbents do not like low pH.
since absorbents  are a polymer of sodium acrylate.  lowering the 
pH covert  sodium acrylate to the acid form (acrylic acid) the acid form is not a super absorbent.